# Python pandas groupby category and integer variables results in pandas last and tail difference

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

**UPDATE:
Please download my full dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/46z49g93tvrkrwv/sf.csv?dl=0).**

my datatype is:

```
>>> df.dtypes
increment       int64
spread        float64
SYM_ROOT     category
dtype: object
```

I have realized that the problem might have been caused by the fact that my `SYM_ROOT` is a category variable. 
To replicate the issue you might want to do the following first:

```
df=pd.read_csv("sf.csv")
df['SYM_ROOT']=df['SYM_ROOT'].astype('category')
```

But I am still puzzled as in why my `SYM_ROOT` will result in the gaps in `increment` being filled with NA? Unless groupby category and integer value will result in a balanced panel by default.

---

I noticed that the behaviour of `pd.groupby().last` is different from that of `pd.groupby().tail(1)`.

For example, suppose I have the following data:

[image]

`increment` is an integer that spans from 0 to 4680. However, for some SYM_ROOT variable, there are gaps in between. For example, 4 could be missing from it.

What I want to do is to keep the last observation per group.

If I do `df.groupby(['SYM_ROOT','increment']).last()`, the dataframe becomes:

[image]

While if I do `df.groupby(['SYM_ROOT','increment']).tail(1)`, the dataframe becomes:

[image]

It looks to me that the `last()` statement will create a balanced time-series data and fill in the gaps with NaN, while the `tail(1)` statement doesn't. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

Your columns `increment` is `category`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],'B':[1,1,2,3],'C':[1,1,1,1]})
df.B=df.B.astype('category')
df.groupby(['A','B']).last()
Out[590]: 
       C
A B     
1 1  1.0
  2  NaN
  3  NaN
2 1  NaN
  2  1.0
  3  1.0
```

When you using `tail` it will not make up the miss level since , `tail` is more like dataframe base , not single columns

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).tail(1)
Out[593]: 
   A  B  C
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  1
3  2  3  1
```

---

After hange it using `astype`

```
df.B=df.B.astype('int')
df.groupby(['A','B']).last()
Out[591]: 
     C
A B   
1 1  1
2 2  1
  3  1
```

Comment: I think it is a different issue from mine

Comment: My increment variable is discontinuous (there are gaps for some of them), while the gap could be filled for other variables.

Comment: Hmmm ... I think my "increment" is integer?

Comment: @JinhuaWang df.dtypes

Comment: I checked, the type is numpy.int64. Unless groupby statement made it change to category?

Comment: I think you are right! It turns out that my SYM_ROOT is category!

Comment: But why would my SYM_ROOT category affect the increment, which is an integer, as well?

Comment: @JinhuaWang I think my answer is clear enough , if you still need more help, please provide more information . like data type , or sample data frame , not picture .

Comment: @JinhuaWang simple fix it by convert to the string , it is a bug i think

Answer (score 0):

It is actually an issue here at [Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17594), where the problem is mainly caused by groupby categories guessing the values.